# CN1 - onTitleScrollAnimation bugged

Tags: java, animation, mobile, codenameone

I have been following the guide from the official CN1 homepage here: https://codenameone.teachable.com/courses/java-for-mobile-devices-introducing-codename-one/lectures/2647773

It worked really well and was a great help to follow through. At the end though, we its about the implementation of the animation to shrink the toolbar, there is an error, that I cannot explain.

That is the snippet:

```
// animations
ComponentAnimation c1 = shoppingList.getToolbar().createStyleAnimation("ShopToolbarShrunk", 200);
ComponentAnimation c2 = titleLabel.createStyleAnimation("TitleShrunk", 200);
ComponentAnimation c3 = fab.createStyleAnimation("FloatingActionButtonShrunk", 200);
shoppingList.getAnimationManager().onTitleScrollAnimation(c1, c2, c3);
```

The code runs and the simulator opens. I can move the mouse wheel or the mouse to scroll the list and the animation starts. Right before the smallest size of the animation, it crashes with the following trace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.Font.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.deriveFont(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.deriveTrueTypeFont(JavaSEPort.java:4841)
    at com.codename1.ui.Font.derive(Font.java:273)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component$2.updateState(Component.java:2625)
    at com.codename1.ui.animations.ComponentAnimation.updateAnimationState(ComponentAnimation.java:95)
    at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager$2.scrollChanged(AnimationManager.java:139)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireScrollEvent(EventDispatcher.java:427)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.setScrollY(Component.java:1879)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.laidOut(Component.java:4409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1430)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1412)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1425)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1412)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1425)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1412)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.revalidate(Container.java:1058)
    at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager$2.scrollChanged(AnimationManager.java:144)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireScrollEvent(EventDispatcher.java:427)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.setScrollY(Component.java:1879)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.laidOut(Component.java:4409)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1430)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1412)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1425)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1412)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1425)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1412)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.revalidate(Container.java:1058)
    at com.codename1.ui.AnimationManager$2.scrollChanged(AnimationManager.java:144)
...
```

The trace repeats endless. One can easily see that this is an infinite loop, causing the java stack to overflow, throwing the exception.

First I though I have different fonts that mess up the animation. However the only font in my theme that is customized is the one of the titlebar, which are set to native:mainthin for both "title" and "titleShrunk" GUID. Even though its the same font, I still get this problem.

The above is a great guide and I was hoping to follow it through till the end, as this is also a very cool animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your project is really out of date which means this issue might have been fixed a long time ago. Please make sure your plugin is up to date then follow the instructions here to make sure your libs are at the latest https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-fix-issue-missing-builds.html

Assuming this still happens please update the stack traces with the new exceptions as the line numbers will be different. Then comment here so I'll see the update to the question and revise the answer.

Comment: Thank you Shai. The plugin was already in the latest version, however I had to update the project libs in the CN1 Settings -> Basic window.
Works fine now, exactly as in your guide :)